# When was the actual Transfiguration of Christ?

Tags: chronology, transfiguration

I can only find one reference online, which is before Lent. Is there multiple dates? or one definite one?

Comment: Are you asking about the Feast of the Transfiguration, which is celebrated yearly, or the original event it commemorates?

Comment: original event it commemorates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual Transfiguration according to [this source](https://www.thoughtco.com/when-is-the-transfiguration-of-our-lord-4046365) took place in February or March: -

> Though the Transfiguration took place in February or March, it has
>   always been celebrated later in the year.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: Catholics have the readings for the Transfiguration on the 2nd Sunday of Letn (which incidentally [is tomorrow](http://www.usccb.org/bible/readings/031217.cfm))

Comment: Anglicans get those readings before Lent, which is arguably a better chronology: the transfiguration occurred before the time in the wilderness.